# Prove that $\mathcal{A}^2= \mathcal{A} \Rightarrow Ker(\mathcal{A})+Ker(\mathcal{A-E})=R^n $, where $\mathcal{A}$ - linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

How we can prove that? I can say, that theirs intersection is  $0$, but no more

Comment: Can you restate what is asked in terms of eigenvalues?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean =(

Comment: What are the eigenvalues of $A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $v\in\Bbb R^n$ as $v=vA+(v-vA)=vA+v(E-A)$ and see what
$A$ and $A-E$ do to $vA$ and $v(E-A)$.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I understand it. v = $(x - A(x)) + A(x)$ and $A( x-A(x)) = 0$ and $(A-E)(A(x)) = 0$